# Solve equation system with partial diff using Newton Method

Tags: newtons-method

I have a question about the following equation system:

[image]

Where mu ist the function of lambdas which I'm looking for. And E0 and C0 are known.

May I solve the non-linear equation system using Newton Method in Matlab? If so, how could it work? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Newton's Method is what you're looking for. Newton's Method is used to find the roots of a *known* function. So if you had an equation f(x1,x2,...)=0, where f was known, you could use Newton's Method to find x1,x2,...

What you have is a first order P.D.E. where the function itself is unknown. There are some numerical ways to solve this, but the answer looks pretty obvious using separation of variables. Also, it's very much a linear P.D.E.